# How to query a Django model (table) and add two related fields from another model (table)? - annotate - left outer join

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to get one specific row (object) from the Movie model(table) and add the maximum rating and the user who posted the maximum rating. Like so:

movie.id | movie.title | movie.description | movie.maximum_rating | movie.maximum_rating_user

Below is is the code I tried.
Unfortunately, my query is returning a queryset which the get() method is not able to work with.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ratings")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ratings")
    score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)
    
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4096)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User, Movie, Rating
from django.db.models import Max, F

def index(request, movie_id):
    movie = Movie.objects.all().annotate(
        maximum_rating=Max('ratings__score'), 
        maximum_rating_user=F('ratings__user')
        ).get(pk=movie_id)
    return HttpResponse(movie)
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the proper query so I can get one specific movie (object/row) with the two add fields from the Ratings model?

**-----------EDIT------------**

When i run below code the following is printed in console:

```
def index(request, movie_id):
    movies = Movie.objects.all().annotate(
            maximum_rating=Max('ratings__score'), 
            maximum_rating_user=F('ratings__user')
            )
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie.id, movie.title, movie.description, movie.maximum_rating, movie.maximum_rating_user)
    return HttpResponse("")
```

| id | title | description | rating | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 8 | 1 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 9 | 1 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 5 | 3 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 8 | 4 |

My code will assure users cannot post the same rating on one movie.
Returning the `HttpResponse(movies)` doesn't provide usefull info.

Seeing the result, I now understand why the `.get(pk=movie_id)` method on the querset is not working.
Anyway, my question still stands.

**----------EDIT2-----------**

As suggested by **Krishna** and **Hector**, the following code creates the object i need. However the structure doesn't feel logical to me (i am django beginner). Also this solution looks more efficient as the query starts off with a specific movie and not dermining the max rating for all movies and then selecting the required movie as per my previous approach.

```
def index(request, movie_id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=movie_id)
    ratings = Rating.objects.filter(movie=movie).order_by('-score')
    rating_obj = ratings.first()
    print(rating_obj.movie.id, rating_obj.movie.title, rating_obj.movie.description, rating_obj.score, rating_obj.user)
    return HttpResponse(f"{rating_obj.movie.id}, {rating_obj.movie.title}, {rating_obj.movie.description}, {rating_obj.score}, {rating_obj.user}")
```

Maybe a little side question.
Should `Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id)`, work?
Normally I would first get the specific movie object and then pass it in like so: `Rating.objects.filter(movie=movie)`. Strangely, doing like so: `Rating.objects.filter(movie=movie_id)` also seem to work. o_O

Comment: can you print the movie in this quey `movie = Movie.objects.all().annotate(maximum_rating=Max('ratings__score'),maximum_rating_user=F('ratings__user'))` and tell me the result

Comment: i think there is a  problem in `ratings__score` that should be `ratings.score` an the same thing with `ratings__user` should be `ratings.user` because you are not query from the Rating model but you are query from Movie model ... not sure if this would solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple is better than complex

```py
def index(request, movie_id):
    rating = Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id).order_by('-score').first()
    return HttpResponse(rating)
```

The problem with this solution is that two users could have added the same maximum value, and that is the reason why you should not and cannot use the `get` method

If you need to access the movie or user object from the template, then you must:

```html
<div class="user">{{ rating.user.get_full_name }}</div>
<div class="movie">{{ rating.movie.title }}</div>
<div class="score">{{ rating.score }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can get max rating of a particular movie by Rating model

```
def index(request, movie_id):
    movie = Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id).order_by('-rating')
    return HttpResponse(movie.first())
```

Comment: Yes, your suggestion seems to provide a solution. However, i do have a hard time wrapping my head around the structure of the returned object (is thid all automatically generate by Django?). Also the `movie_id=movie_id` in your example is not working for me. I have to first get the specific movie object via `movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=movie_id)` and then pass into the query like so `movie=movie`. Am I overloking something?